# How do I export DataGridView Rows with their row color to MS Excel sheet?

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, export-to-excel

I need to know how it's possible to export the rows from my DataGridView to Excel, including their row color.

At this moment I export them but the colors are blank/white/default color.

I need to do this in vb.net

Comment: How do you export them? If you can, post your code so that we can suggest the easiest change. There are too many possible answers to this question without more details.

Comment: Do you use excel-interop, xml format or any other possible solution to export to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
  For Each drow As DataGridViewRow In datagrid1.Rows
      xcel.Cells(yourRowInt, yourColInt).Interior.Color = drow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
  Next
```

Comment: Kindly accept this answer if it works. I've got a _reputation_ to build. Lol. :D

Comment: I don't think that reputation on StackOverflow is of any real [use](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job) unless you are trying to play it like a game and get high-score and level-up xD. This seems like it will format only the first cell, so maybe something like `xcel.Cells(drow.Index + 1, yourColInt).Resize(0, drow.Cells.Count).Interior.Color`

Comment: The row and column index is up to you. I just gave you the idea of changing the cell color based on the grid. Re reps., my friends and I are programmers and we used it to brag with each other. :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?

```
    Private Sub button5_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Const WORKSHEETSTARTROW As Integer = 1
        Const WORKSHEETSTARTCOL As Integer = 1
        Dim excelApp = New Excel.Application
        excelApp.Visible = true
        Dim excelbk As Excel.Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        Dim xlWorkSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelbk.Worksheets("Sheet1"),Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim worksheetRow As Integer = WORKSHEETSTARTROW
        Dim rowCount As Integer = 0
        Do While (rowCount  _
                    < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            Dim worksheetcol As Integer = WORKSHEETSTARTCOL
            Dim colCount As Integer = 0
            Do While (colCount  _
                        < (dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1))
                Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = CType(xlWorkSheet1.Cells(WORKSHEETSTARTROW, worksheetcol),Excel.Range)
                xlRange.Value2 = dataGridView1.Columns(colCount).Name
                worksheetcol = (worksheetcol + 1)
                If (Not (dataGridView1.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Style.Font) Is Nothing) Then
                    xlRange.Font.Bold = dataGridView1.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Style.Font.Bold
                    xlRange.Font.Italic = dataGridView1.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Style.Font.Italic
                    xlRange.Font.Underline = dataGridView1.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Style.Font.Underline
                    xlRange.Font.FontStyle = dataGridView1.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Style.Font.FontFamily
                End If

                worksheetcol = (worksheetcol + 1)
                colCount = (colCount + 1)
            Loop

            worksheetRow = (worksheetRow + 1)
            rowCount = (rowCount + 1)
        Loop

    End Sub
```